# Javascript Multiple Declarations in one line and Learning Javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I work in Java, and all my education is in Java, and I'm trying to figure out what this does to contribute to the Atom text editor. This is a code example from Coffeescript.org:

```
race = function() {
  var runners, winner;
  winner = arguments[0], runners = 2 <= arguments.length ? slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
  return print(winner, runners);
};

if (typeof elvis !== "undefined" && elvis !== null) {
  alert("I knew it!");
}
```

I'm having trouble because I don't understand what the winner line is doing. winner is being assigned as the 0th argument, so you could call: race("nick","jordan","mitchell"), and you would print nick, jordan, mitchell, with winner being nick, and jordan and mitchell being assigned as runners because nick is sliced off. If there are 2 runners, you only have a winner? Or rather, how does that function work?

The second block has two if conditions due to how Javascript has 2 different ways of denoting null, correct?

Do you have any recommendations for learning Coffeescript?

Secondly, any recommendations for beginning to contribute to open source software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick, welcome to Stack Overflow, since this is your first question on any forum. Stack overflow (SO) is primarily a question and answer site, not really a forum. So first bit of advice, you have asked about 3 questions, best if you only ask one, read the how do I ask a good question page on this site for more advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Secondly, any questions that could create debate or potentially could have numerous points of view and opinions are generally frowned upon. This site is purely for questions and answers (not discussions).

So, on to you JavaScript question, that I can help with> I don't know anything about CoffeeScript, apart from it being a more OO wrapper around JavaScript. Personally I say learn JavaScript better. Especially with the advent of the new JavaScript standard (ECMAScript 6) on its way out, it will hopefully make things like CoffeeScript unneeded (IMHO only though).

When you call a function in JavaScript, in addition to the argument defined in the parenthesis, each function gets two other arguments, `this` and `arguments`. Ignoring `this` (apart from saying it is the object context the function is called in , or the global object), the `arguments` argument, is an array like object that contains all of the argument passed into the function.

In your case the function `race` has no parameters defined at all (hence the empty parenthesis `()`), so the function is using the `arguments` argument, the one every function gets by default. The `arguments` parameter can be useful as it means you can write a function in JavaScript that will work with any number of argument you give to it.

Now the race function is also got a lot of shortened syntax, so I will re-write expanded a bit, which may help understanding:

```
race = function () {
    var winner; //Declare two variables, winner and runners, but they are set to undefined
    var runners;

    winner = arguments[0]; //Assign winner to the first argument

    if (arguments.length >= 2) { //If there is 2 or more arguments passed in
        runners = slice.call(arguments, 1); //trim off the first argument (that was Arguments[0], the winner), and assign whats left to runners
    }
    else {
        runners = []; //Set runners to an empty array
    }
    return print(winner, runners); //Call print
};
```

Now the function slice above doesn't seem to be correct to me, that must be in scope somewhere else. Usually it is `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);` as the intention here is to use an array function on an array like object (`arguments`) and the use of the array.prototype and the call execute the function with a different context. Forgive me if I've lost you, but look into JavaScript prototypal inheritance and function reuse in JavaScript should you want to know more.

Now slowly putting back the shortened syntax. declaring variables can be done with one `var` and commas so:

```
var winner;
var runners;
```

can just be

```
var winner,
    runners;

//Or all on one line

var winner, runners;
```

You can then of course include declaration and assignment;

```
var winner = arguments[0],
 runners = 2 <= arguments.length ? slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
```

now the assignment to runners uses a Ternary operator (?:), which is just a one liner for a `if... else` statements i.e. `(test) ? (do this if true) : (do this if false);`

I actually went a bit further. The original still has variable declaration in one statement, then assignments in the next. The original has a comma separating the two assignments. When a comma is used like this in javascript (just to separate expressions) each one is just executed in turn left to right. IMO you don't really gain anything here except the ability to write it on one line, you could quite easily replace it with a semicolon (`;`)

Secondly, `undefined` and `null`. Yes JavaScript has two concepts of nothing. But they both have uses. Firstly when you create a variable and don't assign anything to it i.e. `var a;` JavaScript always sets these to `undefined`. Also any unsupplied arguments in a function call i.e.:

```
function somethingcool(a,b)
{
    //do something cool here
    //If a, or b are not passed in, they will be undefined
}

somethingcool(2); //b will be undefined

somethingcool(); //both a and b will be undefined
```

Now whats the point of `null`, well I tend to use it as a user version of nothing. JavaScript itself never sets anything to `null` so sometimes I do in code, to indicate a nothing value, but I don't want it to be `undefined` as it actually is defined, just nothing.

Also both `undefined` and `null` resolve to false in JavaScripts falsey rules, so that last line could just be

```
if (elvis) {
    alert("I knew it!");
}
```

and potentially work the same (only issue may be empty string `""` as that also resolves to false in JavaScript, which may not be the behavior you're after)
Anyway, if you want to know more just google JavaScript truthy and falsey.

In closing as I said earlier, don't know much about Coffeescript, and I think your question on open source would lead to a more discussion question and opinions and this is not really the correct place

Comment: Wonderful response. Thank you so much for the introduction. I will do my very best to follow the expectations and standards that you outlined. In addition, you were super helpful and approachable with your response. Wish I had the reputation to give you better props!

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is javascript. See OJay's answer for how it works.

---

In coffeescript it would be simpler with the use of [splats(...)](http://coffeescript.org/#splats):

```
race = (winner, runners...) ->
  console.log winner, runners
```

or in ES6:

```
race = function(winner, runners...) {
  console.log(winner, runners);
}
```

As for the second block you would just use the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) in coffeescript:

```
alert "I knew it!" if elvis?
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. The last part is especially helpful!